# How do I hide the codes that appear in the sourcemap in the react application?

Tags: reactjs

All codes are clearly visible in the "sources" section of the internet browser in an application made with react. Is there a method of concealing this?

I searched "Source map disable" and found a few results, but it didn't work.

Screenshot ;

http://serdarkaraca.com/react_serdarkaraca.png

package.json

`"build": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts build && rimraf ./build/**/*.map",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED ;

```
SET GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
npm run build
```